# Unity shader causing loss of detail

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I was working on my game in Unity and starting to experiment with shaders. I was using some code from another project and I do not fully understand how it works so I was hoping for a explanation and how to achieve my goal.

I have two shaders one for "grounds" which are 2d tiles and another for another for objects overtop of those tiles "tilables". I want to control the brightness of the tiles as I am implementing a lighting system. The tillable shader has the ability to make this change but the grounds shader does not.

How can I modify my grounds shader so that I can modify the color and brightness in unity. So far when I use the tilables shader for grounds it works but I loss detail on the tiles. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Grounds shader

```
Shader "Fy/Grounds" 
{
    Properties 
    {
        _MainTex ("Main texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }

    SubShader 
    {
        Cull Back
        Lighting Off
        ZWrite Off
        Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" }
        Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha
        LOD 200

        Pass {
            CGPROGRAM

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct v2f {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                fixed4 color: COLOR; 
            };

            v2f vert(appdata_full v) {
                v2f o;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.color = v.color;


                //
                o.uv = v.vertex.xy/4;
                return o;
            }

            half4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR {
                half4 texcol = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv.xy) * i.color.a;
                return  texcol;
            }

            ENDCG
        } 
    }
}
```

Tilables Shader

```
Shader "Fy/Tilables" 
{
    Properties 
    {
        _MainTex ("Main texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    }

    SubShader 
    {
        Cull Back
        Lighting Off
        ZWrite Off
        Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" }
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        LOD 200

        Pass {
            CGPROGRAM

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma multi_compile_instancing

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            float4 _Color;

            struct v2f {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID              
            };

            v2f vert(appdata_full v) {
                v2f o;
                UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(v);
                UNITY_TRANSFER_INSTANCE_ID(v, o);

                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);
                return o;
            }

            void frag (v2f i, out half4 outDiffuse : SV_Target0) {
                UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(i);
                outDiffuse = tex2D(_MainTex,  i.uv) * _Color;
            }

            ENDCG
        } 
    }
}
```

Can anyone advise on this? Thanks.

Comment: A graphic question without a screenshot, good luck...

Comment: I can't even tell what you're asking for. What does "loss detail on the tiles" mean? And in what way do you want to be able to modify the color and brightness? Right now, the ground shader seems to be using vertex colors.